# Unexpected identifier: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

this for loop is producing an error: Unexpected identifier, why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#done').click(function(e){

       var id = [];
       id = $('.crewMember');
       for(var i=0, i<id.length, i++){
            console.log(id[i]);
       }

    });
});
```

Comment: You're using commas instead of semicolons inside your `for` statement. Aside from that, the "jQuery way" of doing what you're trying to do is: `$('.crewMember').each(function() { console.log(this); });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use semicolon (`;`) instead of comma (`,`) in `for` loop syntax:

```
for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++){
```

The unexpected identifier is because it's expecting multiple variables to be declared/assigned, but you are doing logical comparisons and incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate initialization, condition and final-expression of [for-loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) with semicolons, not commata:

```
for (var i=0; i<id.length; i++)
```

The comma is used to separate [multiple variable declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), so the parser here would expect an `=` after the identifier `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using commas `,` instead of semi-colons `;` in the for loop.